# Using Recursion to Change a Variable

Tags: java, variables, recursion

For a Binary Search Tree, I only have access to the root node, while I am trying to write a recursive method to dig into its left nodes.

For example,

> root.left();

becomes

> root.left().left();

and then,

> root.left().left();

You see where this is going.. Is there a recursive way to change/add on to the variable?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

```
Node node = root;
while (someCondition) {
    node = node.left();
    // do something with the node
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I guess my answer is "you don't need a recursive function".